# How to deploy war in wild fly server?

Tags: java, wildfly, war, adoptopenjdk

we are using one java application in wildfly server which uses java 1.8.0_202, now we want to migrate the java from oracle jdk to adoptopenjdk. I changed the path of new openjdk in management console of wildfly server.
Now the question is do we need again rebuild the application using adoptopenjdk or can i use the old war which is deployed.

Thanks in advance!..

Answer (score 0):

As I cannot comment because of lack of reputation as an answer: 
Normally you can run a Java Application without knowledge of the Java it was built with if the versions match. Second: Why don't you just try it? If you have these strong concerns you should try it in a test environment.

Answer (score 0):

You should not need to do anything to migrate from an Oracle JDK to OpenJDK. Just change the path to the `JAVA_HOME` and that's it. The only possible issues would be if you use Oracle specific API's which one should not be doing anyway :)